# my logo in wordpress not showing in dev

Tags: wordpress, localhost

I built WordPress in localhost when I'm uploading in stagging to dev, my logo can't show however in localhost my logo web is showing. In customize I choose 'Logo only (First Select Logo Above). 
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

May Your Local PHP version and stagging PHP version are different and you may not follow the WordPress coding standards so it may not work on your dev.

Comment: Local PHP version not different with stagging.

Comment: not a major issue but make sure the active theme in your stagging same as local.

Comment: isn't relate with permission or path in local/stagging?

Comment: yeah. give the global path for the get image. like get_template_directory_uri();

Comment: where i must put like get_template_directory_uri(), in folder theme or  ... ?